# Localhost Not Working

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I have been everywhere trying to find a solution to this error: 
when I type in localhost the only thing that comes up is a **blank page**. However when I type in `127.0.0.1` my wamp page comes up.

I know the first thing you will say is have I been to the hosts folder. I have and I deleted everything and on the top line it simply says:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Nothing else.

Then I checked my apache `httpd.conf` file to *make sure* that the ServerName is localhost. It contains the information:

```
ServerName localhost
```

I have changed it to ServerName localhost:80

Apache is the only thing running on `port 80`, I do not have any other versions of Apache running. What could be causing this problem? Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: look in /apache/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf the first entry should be `<VirtualHost *:80> DocumentRoot "C:/localhost" ServerName localhost </virtualHost>` - or something similar ... with carriage returns

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after changing the ServerName?

Comment: I restart Apache every time I make a change in the httpd.conf file

Comment: The first thing to do is find out what happens when you type `ping localhost` at the command line?

Comment: I have wamp running on two machines and when I ping localhost on each of them, I get the same results. 4 packets are sent and received and none are lost.

Comment: @CD001 since that is a virtual host, it should work whether or not the DocumentRoot and the ServerName are set to localhost. I have another WAMP set up where in the httpd-vhost.conf the entries do not reference localhost. HOWEVER localhost still works.

Comment: @user3284579 - true but if you've got VirtualHosting "on" and the default record in `httpd-vhosts.conf` has a different document root configured to that in the main httpd.conf it'll override it. So everything would look OK in httpd.conf but it wouldn't actually resolve *localhost* to where you're expecting it.

Comment: @CD001 I don't have virtual hosting on. Changing it did not make a difference. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a weird problem. But following all the steps above, my localhost still did not work however localhost worked again after I uninstalled and re installed WAMP and restarted the machine.

If you are having a similar issue. Try a re install. Hopefully it will work for you.